# Bigcommerce Authentication code

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, token, bigcommerce

How to get Authentication code ?

I am using https://login.bigcommerce.com/oauth2 url and passing client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&response_type=code{2}{3} in get method, but it gives me  error "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

I know after getting Authentication code I can generate token. But first step is no tclear  how to get Authentication code using login page?

Answer (score 1):

I just went through this oauth token issue and the docs haven't been much help, but once I got going I finally managed to get the app setup by creating my SSL callback page locally on my server. Once I specified that URL in the app settings I was all set. The caveat being I had to do perform the 'install' from the server itself since it wasn't a public URL while logged into BC as the store owner. I was then able to get the temporary token from the querystring and post back to https://login.bigcommerce.com/oauth2/token and obtain the permanent token from the response stream.

You have to include your client id, client secret and the request.querystring["code"] value in your post request.

Here's how I obtained the permanent token which will be inside jsonResponse:

```
string baseURL = "https://login.bigcommerce.com/oauth2/token";
string contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string callbackURL = <your SSL callback URL>

HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(baseURL);
req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
req.ContentType = contentType;
req.Method = "POST";

//Build POST content body
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("client_id={0}", clientID);
sb.AppendFormat("&client_secret={0}", clientSecret);
sb.AppendFormat("&code={0}", tempToken);
sb.AppendFormat("&scope={0}", scopes);
sb.AppendFormat("&grant_type=authorization_code");
sb.AppendFormat("&redirect_uri={0}", callbackURL);
sb.AppendFormat("&context={0}", storeContext);

//Convert the content to byte array and set content length
string contentString = sb.ToString();
byte[] postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contentString);
req.ContentLength = postData.Length;

//Send the data to login server
using (Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
    stream.Flush();
    stream.Close();
}

//Get the request response object
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

//Read the contents of the response
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
string jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Hi I am facing the same confusion , I have the client id , client secret but what I have to put temptoken section and how can I get the store hash for my store.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using something similar to my approach shown above, capture the temporary token during the page_load event of the aspx page defined in your callback URL by reading the value of request.querystring["code"]. You can find your store hash within the store's control panel, one location being legacy API accounts if I recall correctly. HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in the legacy api account my store url is apparing like this http://store-yhatydrhw.mybigcommerce.com , so I think 'yhatydrhw'is my store hash. And also I am struggling with that callback url part . How can I create a local ASP.net application and set it url as a call back url . Can you give me an example.

Comment: Your store hash will be a 5 character alphanumeric value. Store context would be something like stores/ab123. Once you've created your app, specify the callback url such as https://myserver:56789/default.aspx. Create a simple website on your host server using SSL (a self-signed cert will work) that corresponds to the URL you specified for your app. Login to BC as the store owner and 'install the app' from your server. To facilitate grabbing the permanent token, add a response write after the post request since the output will be displayed in an iframe within the BC control panel.

Comment: You can stick the code I posted below into the page_load event, then response write the jsonOutput value so you can see it on screen.